# DateDiff to report different days

Tags: sql, datediff

I am using the the follwoing statement to the datediff but need to amend it.

```
datediff(day, coalesce(nullif(p.u_ser_fire_aov_date, '01/01/1900'), @report_date+1), @report_date) >= 365
```

Rather than using 365 days we need to report on different days

ie 6 months
month

i have a field to record these different days.

how would I incorporate this in the query

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms? (datediff isn't ANSI SQL...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to amend this statement so you can report on different timespans. One option is introduce @days as a parameter in which you set it to say 182 days for six months you could change it to be:

```
coalesce(nullif(p.u_ser_fire_aov_date, '01/01/1900'), @report_date+1), @report_date) >= @days
```

If you can introduce your days field into the query you could use this instead assuming the days field is called Request_days:

```
coalesce(nullif(p.u_ser_fire_aov_date, '01/01/1900'), @report_date+1), @report_date) >= Request_days
```

Would need to see the rest of the query to provide more detail.